# android Webview swf and HTML5 Online audio player not working

Tags: java, html, flash, air

NOTE:I am not including any code because my code is working correctly#
sorry for my English its not my native language, I am new to programming - so the questions can look so childish.....

I am building an android app with JAVA for streaming and downloading audio from internet using android WebView, every thing is ok but one problem.

the player I want to use is based on flash (as2) and its working perfectly if flash player installed on the phone, now since Adobe are no longer supporting flash player development on android, I want to find an up-to-date method to power that swf audio player.

I HAVE TRIED:

1. Adobe air SDK to package my app to apk with/without captive runtime, the problems are

   a. I cant get my other java classes to function, I can only have the swf displayed

   b. The swf player controls (buttons) are not functioning, unlike if flash player is installed
2. HTML5 audio players, the problems is that I used many playlists to select from and play the selected playlist, but html5 players I tried does not support playlist
3. Tried to convert my swf audio player to HTML5, but it cant work only display some rubbish
4. Tried importing my android project to flash builder 4.5.1, so that I can have eclipse ADT with air SDK in one environment, but I got hundreds of errors, (and I cant install ADT plugin to flash builder like in this post http://renaun.com/blog/2011/07/adding-android-development-tools-adt-to-flash-builder-4-5-1/, due to error: Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.)

### THE HELP I NEED: (even one solution is ok)

1.how can I package the app with adobe air sdk and get my java classes work?

2.how to run my swf player smoothly with air runtime just like when I am using flash player for android

3.where can I find a HTML5 player that support playlist

4.is there any good method to convert swf written in ActionScript 2 to HTML5

5.how to solve error complicating dependency when installing new software in flash builder

6.ANY OTHER IDEA OR METHOD TO IMPLIMENT AN AUDIO PLAYER TO A JAVA PROJECT, WITH ABILITY TO SUPPORT PLAYLIST IS WELCOMED.

TOOLS I USED: Air runtime v24, Eclipse with ADT v22, Flash Builder v4.5.1, Flash Professional 4.5

THANKS PROGRAMMERS